# Find total surface area analytically and using matlab

Tags: calculus, matlab

[image]

Hi there, I am trying to solve this question, I got the volume formula as $r^2 \sin \theta \ \mathrm{d} r \ \mathrm{d} \phi \ \mathrm{d} \theta$ but I can not come up with a surface area volume as the top surface facing the cone confuses me. Can anyone please help??

Also I have most of my code ready but I am having issues with the last part of it, should I ask it here as well or go to codestackexchange ??

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spherical part of the surface area is

$$\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}r^2\sin\theta d\theta d\phi=4\cdot\frac\pi4\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\sin\theta d\theta= \frac\pi{\sqrt2} $$

The volume of the spherical section is

$$\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\int_0^2r^2\sin\theta\> drd\theta d\phi= \frac{\sqrt2\pi}3 $$

Comment: May I ask how you obtained r^2 sin theta??

Comment: @Aldo - Consider the surface element as the infinitesimal square with the side length along the $\theta$ direction $rd\theta$ and the side length along the $\phi$ direction $r\sin\theta d\phi$. Together, the surface element is $r^2\sin\theta d\theta d\phi$.

Comment: thanks for explanation!! If you do not mind, would you be able to help with outer shell area as well?  I obtained r^2 *sin(theta)* dtheta*dphi